# How to remove duplicated items from an ArrayList based on quantity

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

First an arraylist with items is created

```
ArrayList<Item> Items
```

Note: item has attribute quantity.
Then, the user will be asked to input the item's name and quantity to be dropped. However, if more than one item with same name appears in the list, the quantity should be added together.
For example, if the list contains "Apple" (quantity 5) and "Apple" (quantity 3), and the user wishes to remove 7 apples from the item list, all the first "Apple" with quantity 5 will be dropped and the second "Apple" will become 1 after dropping. It will be removed once quantity=0

What is the appropriate approach to solve this?

Comment: I think a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) is more suitable.

Comment: Unfortunately the question wants it to be done in Arraylist =(

Comment: What is the current approach?

Comment: What are you supposed to do if the total number of "apples" in the `ArrayList` is less than the amount you wish to remove?

Comment: juz say 'insufficient Apples to be removed'

Comment: You need to iterate over the list and check if you have sufficient items that can be removed and if yes, iterate again and remove them.

Comment: "What is the better approach to solve this?" — better than what?  From your comments, it sounds like this is the approach you're required to follow.  What specific help are you hoping to receive?

Answer (score 2):

- Check if the total amount of quantities is sufficient in the list
- Iterate the list to find an item by name.
- When found, decrease the item's quantity by the input `quantity` to drop -- if the item's quantity gets equal to zero or below, remove the item from the list.  Also decrease the input `quantity` by the item's quantity and break out of the loop as soon as no remaining quantity is available.

```java
public void removeNameQuantity(String name, int q) {

    int totalQ = Items.stream()
            .filter(i -> name.equals(i.getName()))
            .mapToInt(Item::getQuantity)
            .sum();
    if (totalQ < q) {
        System.out.println("Insufficient quantity of " + name + "(s) available");
        return;
        // or throw some appropriate exception
    }
    for (Iterator<Item> it = Items.iterator(); it.hasNext() && q > 0;) {
        Item item = it.next();
        if (name.equals(item.getName())) {
            int iq = item.getQuantity();
            item.setQuantity(iq - Math.min(q, iq));
            if (iq <= q) {
                it.remove();
            }
            q -= iq;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A much better answer than what I posted . Will remove mine

Comment: I don't think you correctly handle the case where the amount to be removed is greater than the amount available.

Comment: The explanatory comment covering this case was not visible below the question